# Identifying the sequence of number string

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

for example we have this string gf_T2fg57342523K_4212

i want to rescue 8 Sequence Numbers so it will be  57342523

another example rt23A98457628Tr5462 will be 98457628

what is the best why to do it ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried in order to achieve this...

Comment: i think about to do for each all the chars in the  string recognize number and count the numbers

Comment: Regular expression would do it. `\d{8}`

Comment: What would you want to happen if your string contains 9 consecutive digits? Would you want to capture 8 characters from it, or do you not want to capture anything?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular expression matching 8 digits:

```
var input = "gf_T2fg57342523K_4212";
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"\d{8}");

if (match.Success)
{
    var number = match.Value;
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Regex.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{8}");
Match match = regex.Match("gf_T2fg57342523K_4212");

string value =  string.Empty;
if(match.Success) // If it is not important to know if it found something you cam suppress this if.
    value = match.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to match strings which contain *only* 8 consecutive digits (and no more), you will need a more complex regular expression than those provided in other answers. Here I've used a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead:

```
(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)
```

Examples:

```
Regex.Match("gf_T2fg57342523K_4212", @"(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)")
> Success, Value = "57342523"
```

```
Regex.Match("gf_T2fg111157342523K_4212", @"(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)")
> Failure
```

See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs) for details on the lookaround grouping constructs.

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = Regex.Matches(rt23A98457628Tr5462, @"\d{8}")
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Value)
                    .ToList();
```